# ¿ Saben el por que cuando ejecuto el comando ng build en la carpeta Dist no me muestra el index.html para el despliege?

Tags: angular, cli

> > este el apartado de arquitectuta, veo que esta la ruta del index.html de mi proyecto y claramento revisando el archivo esta en mi carpeta src pero hago el ng build y no lo veo reflejado en la carpeta dist , claramente esto es una falla puesto que como podria hacer el despliege , muchas gracias.

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/fokuss",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
              "node_modules/datatables.net-bs5/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"
            ]
          },
```

Comment: ¿Lo estás buscando  dentro de `dist/fokuss`? ahí debería estar